# Popcorn-time or other media streamer

Tags: kodi, openelec

Is there any program like popcorn-time for Raspberry Pi?

I have an openelec installed in a Raspberry Pi B+ and I am trying to find a program/plug-in in order to steam movies or other TV series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily apropos to advocate for this, but there are a lot of Kodi/XBMC addons available at [TV Addons](http://www.tvaddons.ag/). Your mileage may vary, but I've heard positive things about the following addons, available through the process of setting up your Kodi system by [installing the addons](http://www.tvaddons.ag/install-addons-kodi/) from there:

- Genesis
- Icefilms
- Navi-X
- ProjectFreeTV

These are listed in the order that *many* would consider to be the most useful. By far the most chaotic and difficult-to-use would be Navi-X, and the easiest and most "download-friendly" would be Genesis.

Again, as in all things, YMMV and if you do choose to go down the road of installing these addons, don't tell anyone that *I* sent you, because I am specifically telling you not to. Now, whether you ignore that advice is on you.

Answer (score 1):

The [Pulsar](http://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=200957) addon can stream torrents:

> Pulsar is an torrent finding and streaming engine. **It doesn't go on torrent websites for legal reasons**. However, it calls specially crafted addons (called **providers**) that are installed separately. They are normal XBMC addons, and thus can be installed/updated/distributed just like any other addon.

As I want to honor the Pulsar's author decision to make it absolutely legal, I won't include here the links to the providers of the sites that Popcorn Time uses. Sorry.

Anyway, in the end, after googling a bit and installing the those providers, Pulsar will be able to play the torrents from the exact same sources that Popcorn Time does.